# How to count all <w:p>nodes based on my specfic criteria using xslt 2.0?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

This is my XML file.

```
<w:document xmlns:w="w">

    <w:body>                    
        <w:p>
          <w:r>
             <w:pict>
                 <v:shape xmlns:v="v">                   
                     <v:textbox>   
                 <w:txbxContent>    
                     <w:p>             <!-- My Ignore case -->
                <w:r>
                       <w:t>paragraph1
                                </w:t>
                               </w:r>
                            </w:p>  
               </w:txbxContent>
                        </v:textbox>
                      </v:shape>
                   </w:pict>
                </w:r>   
                <w:r>
                  <w:t>Normal Paragraph1</w:t>
                </w:r>

              </w:p>

             <w:p>
                <w:r>
                   <w:t>paragraph2
                   </w:t>
                </w:r>
             </w:p>  
             <w:p>
                <w:r>
                   <w:t>paragraph3
                   </w:t>
                </w:r>
             </w:p>  

             <w:p>
                <w:r>
                   <w:t>paragraph4
                   </w:t>
                </w:r>
             </w:p>  
             <w:p>
                <w:r>
                   <w:t>paragraph5
                   </w:t>
                </w:r>
             </w:p>  
           <w:tbl>
              <w:tr>
                 <w:tc>
                     <w:p><w:r><w:t>para6</w:t></w:r></w:p>
                 </w:tc>
                 <w:tc>
                   <w:p><w:r><w:t>para7</w:t></w:r></w:p><!-- Assume This is my Current Node -->
                </w:tc>   
                <w:tc>
                     <w:p><w:r><w:t>para8</w:t></w:r></w:p>
                </w:tc>
              </w:tr>
            </w:tbl>        
   </w:body>

</w:document>
```

**Logic:1**

So, now I want to count all preceding `<w:p>` nodes only within `<w:body>` tag. For example, now we have 5 nodes from `<w:body>`.

**Logic:2**

then if (`<w:tbl>` inside `<w:body>`) then count all `<w:p>` inside the `<w:tbl>` until the current node will reach.

So, the expected final is :7.

I have written query for this, but it is counting wrongly.

```
<xsl:value-of select="count($currentNode/preceding::w:p)"/>
```

It is written 8 because it will also count `<w:p>` inside `<w:p>`(see, my ignore case on my code). I don't want it.

I need the total count like **logic1+logic2**.

Comment: You missed to say which is the current node for which the count is done ???

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev::I mentioned in above Code. Please see para7 <w:p>tag

Comment: @_Saravanan: The text you have given us isn't even a well-formed XML document: undefined namespaces + unclosed tags -- please correct, or your question is not defined at all.

Comment: @_Saravanan: You may be interested to know that there is a simpler and non-misleading XPath expression that computes the required count.

Comment: @_Saravanan: Why do you continue to provide misleading information? It is the `w:p` that contains "para8" -- not the one that contains "para7" as per your last comment. Please, take care to improve the accuracy of your questions -- this one is still totally confusing. More than this, your XML is still non-well-formed -- due to namespaces not defined.

Comment: I am very sorry for that.I have fully modified my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want to ignore **w:p** elements that are nested within other **w:p** elements.

If so, then you need to modify for statement to only include **w:p** element which have no **w:p** element as an ancestor.

```
<xsl:value-of select="count($currentNode/preceding::w:p[not(ancestor::w:p)])"/>
```

This should return a value of 7, instead of 8. I am assuming the current node is **para8** here, by the way.

So, assuming the following XML document

```
<w:document xmlns:w="w">
   <w:body>
      <w:p>
         <w:r>
            <w:pict>
               <v:shape xmlns:v="v">
                  <v:textbox>
                     <w:txbxContent>
                        <w:p><!-- My Ignore case -->
                           <w:r>
                              <w:t>paragraph1 </w:t>
                           </w:r>
                        </w:p>
                     </w:txbxContent>
                  </v:textbox>
               </v:shape>
            </w:pict>
         </w:r>
         <w:r>
            <w:t>Normal Paragraph1</w:t>
         </w:r>
      </w:p>
      <w:p>
         <w:r>
            <w:t>paragraph2 </w:t>
         </w:r>
      </w:p>
      <w:p>
         <w:r>
            <w:t>paragraph3 </w:t>
         </w:r>
      </w:p>
      <w:p>
         <w:r>
            <w:t>paragraph4 </w:t>
         </w:r>
      </w:p>
      <w:p>
         <w:r>
            <w:t>paragraph5 </w:t>
         </w:r>
      </w:p>
      <w:tbl>
         <w:tr>
            <w:tc>
               <w:p>
                  <w:r>
                     <w:t>para6</w:t>
                  </w:r>
               </w:p>
            </w:tc>
            <w:tc>
               <w:p>
                  <w:r>
                     <w:t>para7</w:t>
                  </w:r>
               </w:p>
            </w:tc>
            <!-- Assume This is my Current Node -->
            <w:tc>
               <w:p>
                  <w:r>
                     <w:t>para8</w:t>
                  </w:r>
               </w:p>
            </w:tc>
         </w:tr>
      </w:tbl>
   </w:body>
</w:document>
```

If you use the following XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:w="w">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

   <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:variable name="currentNode" select="//w:p[w:r/w:t = 'para8']" />
      Old: <xsl:value-of select="count($currentNode/preceding::w:p)"/> 
      -----
      New: <xsl:value-of select="count($currentNode/preceding::w:p[not(ancestor::w:p)])"/> 
   </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Then the following is returned:

```
  Old: 8 
  -----
  New: 7
```

Comment: :Thanks a lot.please Let me try it... i will come soon

Comment: @@Tim::Great work tim... Thank you very much...It's working absolutely fine...Thanks for your time...

Comment: @@Tim::Could you please refer any good books for XSLT programming?.i am very interesting in learning xslt.Kindly refer any books for me

Comment: @Saravanan: See this reply about good XSLT books/resources: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/339930/any-good-xslt-tutorial-book-blog-site-online/341589#341589

Comment: @Tim C: This expression is equivalent to: `count($currentNode/preceding::w:p)` because the `preceding::` and `ancestor::` axes are non-overlapping ! Please, revise and correct your answer. Also, it would be great if you also provide the XML document against which you are evaluating this XPath expression -- the question doesn't provide a well-formed XML document and two people may construct two different well-formed XML documents based on this.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev I have amended my question to show my working, but I do get different results when I do `count($currentNode/preceding::w:p[not(ancestor::w:p)])` instead of `count($currentNode/preceding::w:p)`

Comment: @Tim C: OK, I misunderstood your answer -- sorry. And it is correct. I think the confusion results from the bad description of the problem -- I still am not sure what is the initial context node.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev No problem. It confused me for a long time too, but you were right to say I should have provided much more detail in my original answer to make it clear what I was using.